# Access Denied: Project project_id: "erudite-buckeye-303218" gaia_id: 546380511156 : User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project er

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to using BigQuery.  I tried to select my trial project `vertical-idea-303617` and run a query against it.  But the browser keeps complaining about permissions related to `erudite-buckeye-3032181`.  I don't know what that `erudite-buckeye-3032181` project is and I do not have it selected.  Why am I still getting errors?  See this image here:

[image]

How do I run queries against my `vertical-idea-303617.perftest.reportgraphs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, not exactly the same, and to solve it I just had to click that `Hide Preview Features` button.

apparently Google released some new features that are all broken in the new Front-end, but not in the old